# SQLiteDatabase NullPointerException while querying the DB with a SELECT statement

Tags: nullpointerexception, android-cursor, sqlite

i'm trying to query my database to check if a matching field value exists or not.

Pretty much using a SELECT sql statement.

I'm getting an NullPointerException error when i try to query the database even though the database is already open.

The following code is from the class holds all the SQLite methods:

```
public long createDBCard(String card_name, String card_type, String attributeType, 
            String summonRequirements, String card_description, 
            String spellSpeed, int levelStars, int rankStars, int atk_stat, int def_stat, 
            String setnumber, int cardNumberPass) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

    String passedCardName = card_name;
    //long l = Long.parseLong(passedCardName);
    String returnedCardName = getCardName(passedCardName);
    long numCards = Countcards();
    String numCardmsg = String.valueOf(numCards);

    if (numCards == 51){
        Toast h1 = Toast.makeText(CarddbAdapter.this, "Error counting card records.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        h1.show();
    }else if(numCards == 0){
        Toast h = Toast.makeText(this, "No cards exists", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        h.show();
    }else if(numCards >= 1){
        Toast b = Toast.makeText(CarddbAdapter.this, returnedCardName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        b.show();
    }else{
        Toast b = Toast.makeText(CarddbAdapter.this, "FAIL!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        b.show();
    }

    cv.put(KEY_CARDNAME, card_name);
    cv.put(KEY_CARDTYPE, card_type);
    cv.put(KEY_ATTRIBUTETYPE, attributeType);
    cv.put(KEY_SUMMONREQUIREMENTS, summonRequirements);
    cv.put(KEY_CARD_DESCRIPTION, card_description);
    cv.put(KEY_SPELLSPEED, spellSpeed);
    cv.put(KEY_LEVELSTARS, levelStars);
    cv.put(KEY_RANKSTARS, rankStars);
    cv.put(KEY_ATK_STAT, atk_stat);
    cv.put(KEY_DEF_STAT, def_stat);
    cv.put(KEY_SETNUMBER, setnumber);
    cv.put(KEY_CARDNUMBERPASS, cardNumberPass);
    return ourDatabaseW.insert(DATABASE_TABLE_CARDS, null, cv);
    //return 51;
}

public String getCardName(String passedName)  throws SQLException{
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_CARDNAME};
        Cursor c = ourDatabaseR.query(DATABASE_TABLE_CARDS, columns, KEY_CARDNAME + "='" + passedName + "'", null, null, null, null);
        if (c != null){
            c.moveToFirst();
            String name = c.getString(0);
            return name;
        }
        return "hello";
    }
```

LogCat Error

```
05-11 01:15:49.456: E/AndroidRuntime(1509): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-11 01:15:49.456: E/AndroidRuntime(1509): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{cybertech.productions.yugiohlibrary/cybertech.productions.yugiohlibrary.LoadingScreen}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-11 01:15:49.456: E/AndroidRuntime(1509):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
05-11 01:15:49.456: E/AndroidRuntime(1509):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
05-11 01:15:49.456: E/AndroidRuntime(1509):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
05-11 01:15:49.456: E/AndroidRuntime(1509):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
05-11 01:15:49.456: E/AndroidRuntime(1509):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-11 01:15:49.456: E/AndroidRuntime(1509):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-11 01:15:49.456: E/AndroidRuntime(1509):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
05-11 01:15:49.456: E/AndroidRuntime(1509):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-11 01:15:49.456: E/AndroidRuntime(1509):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-11 01:15:49.456: E/AndroidRuntime(1509):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
05-11 01:15:49.456: E/AndroidRuntime(1509):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
05-11 01:15:49.456: E/AndroidRuntime(1509):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-11 01:15:49.456: E/AndroidRuntime(1509): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-11 01:15:49.456: E/AndroidRuntime(1509):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:80)
05-11 01:15:49.456: E/AndroidRuntime(1509):     at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:89)
05-11 01:15:49.456: E/AndroidRuntime(1509):     at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:231)
05-11 01:15:49.456: E/AndroidRuntime(1509):     at cybertech.productions.servicehelpers.CarddbAdapter.createDBCard(CarddbAdapter.java:144)
05-11 01:15:49.456: E/AndroidRuntime(1509):     at cybertech.productions.yugiohlibrary.LoadingScreen.onCreate(LoadingScreen.java:37)
05-11 01:15:49.456: E/AndroidRuntime(1509):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-11 01:15:49.456: E/AndroidRuntime(1509):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
05-11 01:15:49.456: E/AndroidRuntime(1509):     ... 11 more
```

In one of my Activities i use an Object of the class to call the createDBCard() method.

Any help would be appreciated.

I tried playing around with the rawQuery() method but had errors, lol.

Comment: What line is throwing the NullPointerException?

Comment: It doesn't exactly tell me in the logcat, but i know it has something to do with the getCardName() method.

Comment: Could you edit the question to show the logcat error?

Comment: Which line is line 144 in the above code?

Comment: Toast b = Toast.makeText(CarddbAdapter.this, returnedCardName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, for now to where it returns my query result.

After debugging something else related to how i designed my open() method i found out, i guess from trying different things to solve some earlier errors, i declared the context as **this** instead of my pre-defined **private final ourContext**.

Below is the first debugged code that solved my later problem with my **createDBCard()** method, the NullPointerException.

My open() method after i declared my **private final ourContext;** before the DbHelper class with the rest of my other variables:

The one coded wrong below:

```
public CarddbAdapter open() throws SQLException{
        ourHelper = new DbHelper(this);
        ourDatabaseW = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ourDatabaseR = ourHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        return this;
    }
```

The one coded right below:

```
public CarddbAdapter open() throws SQLException{
        ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
        ourDatabaseW = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ourDatabaseR = ourHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        return this;
    }
```

As you can see i changed **ourHelper = new DbHelper(this);** to **ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);**

Doing this made me realize i needed to change all the **Toasts** in my **createDBCard()** to use my pre-defined **ourContext** instead of **this**.

Thanks all for trying to help.